# Unable to make connection using TLSv1.2

Tags: java, ssl, paypal, tls1.2

I am new to SSL connection. I need to make HTTPS connection using TLSv1.2 in Java 7 since PayPal has moved its sandbox environment to TLSv1.2. I tried following code as found in other posts to enable tlsv1.2 and make a secure connection using HttpClient.

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);

final SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();


final Scheme scheme = new Scheme("https", sslContext.getSocketFactory(), 443);
schemeRegistry.register(scheme);

final BasicClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I'm getting error on creating Scheme with sslContext.getSocketFactory() since it is of type SSLSocketFactory and Scheme is looking for SocketFactory. I tried to typecast the same but returned in same problem. Please help if I'm missing something.

Comment: An `sslsocketfactory` is a `socketfactory`. What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Yes, SSLSocketFactory is socketfactory, when i tried to implement the same way, it says the constructor is undefined, and when i try to type cast the same, it throws ClassCastException